# Power Of a negative number, moving decimal

Tags: self-learning, decimal-expansion

I need help. I don't understand what the number looks like when I get given a to the power of after it.

I've calculated a number:

0.999^14(1-0.999)^1

It gives me the result:

9.86090637x10^-04

Where I'm confused is : x10^04

Does this mean the decimal place should move forward 4 places, giving me the number:

0.000986090637

What is the multiplier at the end telling me about my number?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to understand: you have both $10^{-04}$ and $10^{0.4}$.

Comment: The first one is $10^{-4}$ that means: $\dfrac {1} {10^4}$.

Comment: The second one is a "weird" way to write $10^{4/10}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to clear up this bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. It just means $9.86090637\times 10^{-4}$, so the decimal point should be moved forward $4$ places.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion. I appreciate the help.